# mysql_connect doesn't work second time

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect, mysql-error-1005

duplicate of unanswered: [How to reconnect in php adodb after exceptions: Mysql server gone away or Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26174159/3338098)

mysql_connect works the first time, but never works after that...

```
$connectDb = mysql_connect(secret, secret, secret);
mysql_select_db("secret", $connectDb);

$sleepPeriod = 1800;
sleep($sleepPeriod);
while (true) {
  $result = mysql_query("good query", $connectDb);
  if (!$result) {
    if (mysql_error()=='MySQL server has gone away') {
      echo "MySql connection was disconnected... reconecting...\n";
      $connectDb = mysql_connect(secret, secret, secret);
      mysql_select_db("secret", $connectDb);
      continue;
    } else {
      die("Invalid Query: ".__FILE__.':'.__LINE__.' '.mysql_error()."\n");
    }
  }
  //DO STUFF
  sleep($sleepPeriod);
}
```

if a timeout or disconnect happens `mysql_connect` seems to fail and `mysql_error` continually returns `"MySQL server has gone away"`, which results in an infinite loop that can go for days.  is there some other way to clear the error response of `mysql_error` or to make `mysql_connect` run a second time without having to restart this program manually or resorting to cron.

I just noticed that `mysql_connect` has a strange(stupid?) parameter called `new_link`, however it would be an outrageous design if php's mysql code purposefully disables reconnects on timeout by default... I'll test regardless and get back.

Comment: I would not do it like this, just do your stuff and exit the script. You can use cron or a task scheduler to run your job periodically.

Comment: i have scripts just like this that need the flexibility to run once a second, every 5 seconds/ every 5 minutes... hours... days...  I would either have to code them differently depending on the period alone, or code them all the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_connect` doesn't care if the connection has disconnected or timed-out it will *never* connect a second time unless you call it with the parameter `new_link` with the value `true`.

```
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password,true);
```